# How to get selected text on safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I want to write a plugin that translate user-selected text. But I stalled on "getting the selected text". I tried a lot of options, but none of them does not work (probably my fault).

Now my **global.html** looks like this:

```js
<script >

// Set up Listener(s)
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);  

// Functions to perform when event is received
function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === "contextmenutranslate") {
        alert("first");
        alert(window.getSelection());
    }
}

</script>
```

Second alert returns empty string.
What am I doing wrong?
What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global page cannot interact with any web pages directly for security reasons. So, to get selected text from a page, you need to use an injected script. You can then use [messages](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html) to communicate between your global page and the injected script.

For example:

#### global.js

```
safari.application.addEventListener('command', performCommand, false);
safari.application.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === 'contextmenutranslate') {
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage('getselection');
    }
}

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'theselection') {
        alert(msg.message);
    }
}
```

#### injected.js

```
safari.self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'getselection') {
        var sel = window.getSelection()+'';
        safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('theselection', sel);
    }
}
```

Remember to set injected.js as a start or end script in the Safari Extension Builder.

Comment: It works, but sometimes alert() calls more than one time. Did you know why?

Comment: That's possibly due to iframes on the page - the injected script is injected into all of them. Maybe try checking `if (window == window.top)` within the `handleMessage` function in the injected script.